# Visual Studio 2022 .NET MAUI Project Settings will not save location of Android KeyStore file

Tags: android, maui, visual-studio-2022, android-keystore

I am trying to set the path to my KeyStore file in the Android section of the project properties for my .Net Maui project.  I click on the browse button, select the KeyStore file, and when the settings page re-appears, the box for the location of the KeyStore is still empty.  I cannot figure out why VS 2022 keeps doing this.  Any ideas?

Below is the screen shot from the settings page:

[image]

I  click the Browse button to the right of the Key Store text box however the text box never has a value after I select the Keystone File.

I can turn the auto .APK signature off and manually select the same keystore file during an Adhoc deployment and it works fine.

Comment: May I know what's the version of your Visual Studio?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I can't reproduce the issue that the package Signing keystore value not be saved when opening the setting page again.

However, you can also manually add the KeyStore file in your csproj file like:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(TargetFramework)|$(Platform)'=='Release|net8.0-android|AnyCPU'">
          <AndroidSigningKeyStore>C:\Users\...\YourProjectName\YourProjectName.keystore
         </AndroidSigningKeyStore>
           
</PropertyGroup>
```

For more details, you can refer to [Define build properties in your project file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/android/deployment/publish-cli?view=net-maui-8.0#define-build-properties-in-your-project-file).

Additionally, it's suggested to report Visual Studio tooling issues is via Visual Studio's "Report a Problem" menu and then follow them on the developer community site. Please see [How to report a problem with Visual Studio - Visual Studio | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-report-a-problem-with-visual-studio?view=vs-2022&viewFallbackFrom=vs-201). I found a similar thread:[Maui add keystore not saving filepath](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Maui-add-keystore-not-saving-filepath/10490256?q=maui) that you can refer to.